# Grails Scaffold - Generated MySQL Column Type for JodaTime DateTime field

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I am new to Grails and am using Grails 2.1 with a MySQL 5.5 backend to build a sample project to learn.

I installed JodaTime 1.4 Plug-in and then ran `grails install-joda-time-templates`

However, when I declared a Domain Class field to be of type org.joda.time.DateTime, I got an error when attempting to save a new entry.

In order to isolate the problem, I created a simple Domain Class:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

class Project
{
    String name
    DateTime startDate

    static constraints = {
        name(blank: false, maxSize: 50)
        startDate(validator: {return (it > new DateTime())})
    }
}
```

The controller just sets scaffold to use the Domain Class.

My DataSource.groovy specifies `dbCreate = "create-drop"`, as I am letting the tables get created by Grails.

Here is the error I get when I try to save:

```
Class:com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation
Message:Data truncation: Data too long for column 'start_date' at row 1
```

When I look at project.start_date column in the MySQL database that Grails created, the type is TINYBLOB.

My thought is that TINYBLOB may not be sufficient to store the data for a JodaTime DateTime field.

Does anyone know how I can make Grails create an appropriate type?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you checked the Joda Time plugin? http://grails.org/plugin/joda-time

Comment: @SérgioMichels, I did, and I went through the JodaTime integration for Grails chapters on [Data Binding](http://gpc.github.com/grails-joda-time/guide/dataBinding.html) and [Scaffolding](http://gpc.github.com/grails-joda-time/guide/scaffolding.html), but did not find a way I could force the JodaTime DateTime to map to a specific MySQL Type.

Comment: Can you try static mapping = { startDate sqlType:'timestampt' } ?

Comment: @Sérgio Michels Thank you for this idea.  I tried it, and it did cause the MySQL table/column that was created by Grails to have a type of timestamp.  When I go to MySQL Workbench, I see project.start_date of type timestamp.  However, I still get an error when persisting, it is a new error: `Class:com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation        Message:Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '¬í' for column 'start_date' at row 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Config.groovy:

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    "user-type" type: PersistentDateTime, class: DateTime
    "user-type" type: PersistentLocalDate, class: LocalDate
}
```

And your mapping closure:

```
static mapping = {
    startDate type: PersistentDateTime
}
```

Take a look at [this post](http://adhockery.blogspot.com.br/2010/06/defaulting-joda-time-hibernate-types.html) for more info, see if it helps.

Comment: Tiago, that worked, thank you very much for the answer and the very useful blog post link.  The only additional change I had to make was to make was to get JodaTime Hibernate for the `org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime` dependency.  I did this by specifying [JodaTime Hibernate 1.3](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/index.html) in the dependencies closure of BuildConfig.groovy.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked. Accept the answer for future reference pls.

Comment: This doesn't work for Grails 2.3.10 and Hibernate 4. I get a NoClassDefFoundError (SessionImplementor) when the app is starting =/ , any clues on how to fix it for that version of Grails?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to make it work (Grails 2.1):

1) add to buildConfig:

```
compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:1.9"
```

2) refresh the dependencies

3) run this command to add the user-type supported:

```
grails install-joda-time-gorm-mappings
```

4) finally in the domain class:

```
import org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.*

static mapping = {
 column_name type: PersistentDateTime
}
```

Documentation was found here: [persistence](http://gpc.github.com/grails-joda-time/guide/persistence.html)

Comment: there is no need to add static mapping.